# How to write an init script

Tags: init.d

I am developing an automatic watering system on my Pi. The code is C#, run under Mono.

I want the system to start automatically when the Pi boots up, so I am trying to create a script in init.d.

I copied a script for something else, and just changed the program to run, but I keep getting

```
 WateringSystem.serviceFailed to start WateringSystem.service: Unit WateringSystem.service failed to load: No such file or directory
```

Here is my code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          WateringSystem
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $time $syslog
# Should-Start:      ntp
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start WateringSystem daemon at boot time
# Description:       Start WateringSystem daemon at boot time.
### END INIT INFO
# pidfiles:          $prefix/var/WateringSystem.pid
################################################################################


# add to the shared library search path
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
NAME=WateringSystem
RUN_DIRECTORY=/home/pi/$NAME
INSTALL_DIR=/home/pi/$NAME
DAEMON_PID=/var/run/$NAME.pid
DAEMON="mono -debug $INSTALL_DIR/WateringSystem.exe"
LOGDIR=/var/log

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been started
        #   1 if daemon was already running
        #   2 if daemon could not be started
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $DAEMON_PID --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
                || return 1
        if [ "$1" -eq 1 ] ; then
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --no-close --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $DAEMON_PID --exec $DAEMON --chdir $RUN_DIRECTORY \
                $DAEMON_ARGS \
                || return 2
        else
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $DAEMON_PID --exec $DAEMON --chdir $RUN_DIRECTORY -- \
                $DAEMON_ARGS -L$LOGDIR/$NAME\
                || return 2
        fi
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Listing"
        ls -ld $DAEMON
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start 0
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
    start-trace)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        do_start 1
        case "$?" in
                0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
                2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
    stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --pidfile $DAEMON_PID --name $NAME\
            --exec $DAEMON --retry 5
        RETVAL="$?"
        [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
        rm -f $DAEMON_PID
        exit "$RETVAL"
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop  && sleep 2
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        start-stop-daemon --status --pidfile $DAEMON_PID
        RUNNING=$?
        if [ $RUNNING -eq 0 ]; then
            echo -n "Running ($RUNNING) PID:"
            cat $DAEMON_PID
        else
            echo "NOT Running ($RUNNING)"
        fi
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?

        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

I have never used start-stop-daemon before, so I don't know what is wrong.

Do I have to add some more files somewhere to tell systemd how to run my server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init.d` may still work - `systemd` tries to make a `.service` from `init.d` scripts, but you would be better to write a `systemd` service.

Services should all specify full paths to executables.

You appear to have a more fundamental problem. `$INSTALL_DIR/WateringSystem.exe` does not look like an `ARM` executable.

The first step before automating any script is to run it manually and ensure it actually works.

Comment: The command I wanted to run is `/usr/bin/mono -debug $INSTALL_DIR/WateringSystem.exe`. Now I have fixed the obvious mistake you pointed out, and put the full path in, it works! Thanks!

Comment: It is starting the program now, but the stop command isn't killing the process. How can I debug that?